# if else statement format in batch file

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, if-statement

I am new to batch scripting and am trying to execute the following `if` statement and the command prompt returns an error concerning the syntax.  I have searched around on the internet and cannot seem to get a straight answer on how to do an if else statement in a batch file.  What is the proper way to format this statement? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if !cnt! geq 20 (
                    if !size! lss 5000000(sent>%cd%\EmailSent.txt
                        mailsend1.19.exe -to !email! -from test@gmail.com -ssl -smtp smtp.gmail.com -port 465 -sub "test" -M "The capture quality is not sufficient.  Please retake capture." -auth-plain -user "test@gmail.com" -pass) else(sent>%cd%\EmailSent.txt
                        mailsend1.19.exe -to !email! -from test@gmail.com -ssl -smtp smtp.gmail.com -port 465 -sub "test" -M "The capture quality is ok. Patient good to go." -auth-plain -user "test@gmail.com" -pass )
                    )
```

Comment: It should also be `echo sent` not `sent` in `sent>%cd%\EmailSent.txt%`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best code, but this is more or less how.

```
@echo off
IF %this%==not_this (
     echo no match
) ELSE IF %this%==this (
     echo matches
) ELSE (
     echo Did not find match
)
```

You can test it by doing `set this=this` or `set this=not_this` or `set this=something_else` before running the script to see different results.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "string1" operator "string2" (dothis) else (dothat)
```

spaces significant. `) else (` must be on a single line.

```
if "string1" operator "string2" (
 dothis
 then dothis
 after that dothis
) else (
 dothat
 then dothat
 after that dosomethingelse
)
```

Comment: Yes I know that. How would I do multiple line if else statements?

Answer (score 0):

I'd reduce redundancy and use a better indenting:

```
Set MailArgs=-to !email! -from test@gmail.com -ssl -smtp smtp.gmail.com -port 465 -sub "test" -auth-plain -user "test@gmail.com" -pass 
if !cnt! geq 20 (
    if !size! lss 5000000 (
        sent>%cd%\EmailSent.txt
        mailsend1.19.exe %MailArgs% -M "The capture quality is not sufficient. Please retake capture."
    ) else ( 
        sent>%cd%\EmailSent.txt
        mailsend1.19.exe %MailArgs% -M "The capture quality is ok. Patient good to go."
    )
)
```

It's unclear to me what the `sent>%cd%\EmailSent.txt` should do.

Comment: the OP asked how to do multiple `else if` he specifically says 'if else'

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Literally he asked `What is the proper way to format this statement?`

Comment: the heading `if else statement format in batch file` the content `I have searched around on the internet and cannot seem to get a straight answer on how to do an if else statement in a batch file` and the comment in Magoo's answer `Yes I know that. How would I do multiple line if else statements?`

Answer (score 0):

I have added this answer only because your and LotPings code blocks both contain unnecessary code. *(The email is being sent in each scenario meaning that you can send and write to file only once)*.

```bat
If !cnt! GEq 20 (
    If !size! Lss 5000000 (
        Set "_M=The capture quality is not sufficient.  Please retake capture."
    ) else (
        Set "_M=The capture quality is ok.  Patient good to go."
    )
    MailSend1.19.exe -to !email! -from test@gmail.com -ssl -smtp smtp.gmail.com -port 465 -sub "test" -M "!_M!" -auth-plain -user "test@gmail.com" -pass
    Echo sent>"%cd%\EmailSent.txt"
)
```